# How do I check if a record already exists in sql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple **table** with two fields ( **name** and **id** ), it already consists of some values. How do i check if the **name** already exists and if it exists then check for **id** if it matches with the corresponding name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a select for them and see if any rows are returned. Kinda obvious really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For php and mysql:

```
    $sql = "select * from `table` where name = "' username '"";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
      //username is present
    } else {
      //username is not present
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 Select id from table where name =?
```

if you get an **id** the name exist, if not, the name doesnt

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
Select count(*) from table where name = @name and id = @id
```

Thank you...